# MVC PHPMailer flow

Tags: php, phpmailer

I would like to use `PHPMailer` in my MVC site but the view content doesn't come for the $emailTemplate variable. This is my own MVC. The problem starts here: 
    `$emailTemplate = $this->view('emails/expirityRemainder');` Could somebody tell me how to manage that change?

If I will do that everything works fine, but I need to load different views: 
    `$emailTemplate = 'The email body';`

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class Emails extends Controller{

    //Send email to remamber the expirity date
    public function sendReinder($data){ 
        $emailTemplate = $this->view('emails/expirityRemainder');
        $data=[
            'recipient'=>'anEmail@yahoo.com',
            'subject'=>'TheSubject',
            'htmlBody'=>$emailTemplate,
            'nonHtmlBody'=>'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients',
            'sentMessage'=>'Message has been sent'
        ];
        $email = new Email();
        $email->sendMail($data);
    }
}
```

The 'expirityRemainder.php' file contains a text:
    `Here will be the HTML code formatted`

The PHPMailer file is inside of that libraries/PHPMailer folder.
The Email class send the email (on my server the below blank details are filled):

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
class Email{
    public function sendMail($data){


        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
        try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers smtp.topwebdeveloper.co.uk
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                     // TCP port to connect to 465 25 587

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('', '');
        //$mail->addAddress('', '');     // Add a recipient
        //$mail->addAddress('');               // Name is optional
        $mail->addAddress($data['recipient'], 'Nameee');
        $mail->addReplyTo('', 'Information');


        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = $data['htmlBody'];
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
        print_r($data);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
            print_r($data);
        }

    }
}

?>
```

This is the output:

```
Here will be the html code formatted
Message could not be sent. 
Mailer Error: Message body emptyArray ( [recipient] => anEmail@yahoo.com [subject] => TheSubject [htmlBody] => [nonHtmlBody] => This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients [sentMessage] => Message has been sent )`
```

I think the view content is expected to not be a string... The `$data['htmlBody']`inside if sendMail($data) did not receive the view content.

The view method works perfect for my MVC, except that situation when I try to load an mail text:

```
<?php
        class Controller{
            public function model($model){
                require_once '../app/models/'.$model.'.php';
                return new $model();
            }

            public function view($view, $data=[]){
                if(file_exists('../app/views/'.$view.'.php')){
                    require_once '../app/views/'.$view.'.php';
                } else {
                    die('vien not exists');
                }
            }
        }
```

I created a new method but still not working:

```
<?php
    public function loadEmailView($view, $data=[]){
        if(file_exists('../app/views/'.$view.'.php')){

            //ob_start();
            //include('../app/views/'.$view.'.php');
            //$file = ob_end_flush();

            //echo file_get_contents('../app/views/'.$view.'.php');

            //$data['htmlBody'] = require_once '../app/views/'.$view.'.php';

        } else {
            die('Email vien not exists');
        }
    }
```

None of the 3 above solutions not add the view content to my `htmlBody` variable:

```
<?php
class Emails extends Controller{

    //Send email to remamber the expirity date
    public function sendReinder($data){ 
        $emailTemplate = $this->loadEmailView('emails/expirityRemainder');
        //$emailTemplate = file_get_contents('email_template.php');
        $data=[
            'recipient'=>'anEmail@yahoo.com',
            'subject'=>'TheSubject',
            'htmlBody'=>$emailTemplate,
            'nonHtmlBody'=>'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients',
            'sentMessage'=>'Message has been sent'
        ];
        $email = new Email();
        $email->sendMail($data);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where does this _"PHPMailer file"_ come into it? What is the `Email` class? What **exactly** does its `sendMail` method look like?

Comment: The problem appears to be around the `$this->view()` call which looks to be displaying the output instead of capturing it in a string. What MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my post, there are your requested details.

Comment: The working version is that `$emailTemplate = 'The email body';` but I need to load different views depend on the situation, the reason for trying that solution: `$emailTemplate = $this->view('emails/expirityRemainder');`

Comment: What is the `view()` method? What does it return?

Comment: Please see the post (I have edited, now it contain all the details you need)

Comment: Right, so your `view` method returns nothing. Can you see the problem then?

Comment: That way is working fine my MVC, now I try to find a solution to include that mail template. I have tried a few solutions but still the same result. See my new method, I have updated my post.